# Xcode Build Error: No account for team "S23Q9DM44M"

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode builds a [barcode reader app](https://github.com/rickwierenga/heartbeat-tutorials/tree/master/BarcodeScanner/BarcodeScanner-Final) without error for the simulator, however, the build for an iPhone XR returns errors:
[image]

## ERROR MESSAGE

```
No account for team "S23Q9DM44M". Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials. (in target 'BarcodeScanner')
```

## QUESTIONS

What is "team S23Q9DM44M"?

**What exactly is the problem?**  Explanations or a narrative explaining the problem, which is geared for an undergraduate that has taken a C++ course is sought.

First error message:  Is "S23Q9DM44M" a string that needs to be hunted down in the file and replaced?  What would it be replaced with?

Any suggestions for the second error are also appreciated.

## UPDATES

- I do NOT want to distribute my App to others
- I DO want to run the App on my iPhones / iPad
- I did not pay the $99 developer membership

Comment: Are you a paid developer or using a stand alone AppleID to sign your builds and into Xcode? The [path to resolution is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674208/development-team-not-showing-in-xcode) based on which account you choose

Comment: You must sign in as a developer and whether you pay or not devices what code signing permissions you are granted. Who authored the code? If you are allowed to modify it, they might be the best to explain how to stripping out the team credentials from the code you found / downloaded / inherited / licensed.

Comment: @bmike  I have updated the first sentence with a Github link to the code.

Answer (score 2):

When you're building an app to run on an iPhone, it needs to be code signed. Signing is tied to your Apple developer account, so you must be logged in to that account in Xcode in order to sign the app-- even if you're not going to use the app store. You can't build the app and deploy it to an iPhone without signing. The simulator doesn't need signing, which is why it works there.

`S23Q9DM44M` is a team ID. It might be a team you belong to, or it might be another team (if you got this project from someone else). Xcode is telling you that it doesn't currently have access to this team, so it can't sign the app.

You need to:

1. Go to Xcode preferences, in the "accounts" section, and log in to your Apple developer account. If you don't have an account, you need to create one first. You can do this at https://developer.apple.com/programs/. It's free if you're not going to use the app store.
2. Go to this project's "signing and capabilities" settings. In the "team" section, make sure the correct developer team is selected. This might just be your name, or it might be a company or group that you work with. Then, check the provisioning profile setting. It might say "Xcode managed profile", in which case you're set. If it shows a pop-up menu, use it to select a provisioning profile.

Update: I tried the Github project you linked to. Besides the above, you also need to change the bundle ID for the app. Your question doesn't mention any bundle ID issues but that's because you had something else to fix first.

The bundle ID of iOS apps must be unique since it's how iOS identifies the app. Apple checks the bundle ID when compiling and tries to register it with your developer account. If someone else is using the ID then you need to change it. This is also found in the "signing and capabilities" page in Xcode. The ID can be anything unique but the normal format is a reverse domain name-style ID. For example your domain were `apple.stackexchange.com` then you might use `com.stackexchange.apple.barcodescanner`.